# python indent error on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-tesseract

I have the following code that does some ocr stuff. When this is done i want to generate some windows. But whenever i run my code i get the following error on line 13: `unindent does not match any outer indentation level` i think this is weird because i dont see any weird indents in my code. See my code below:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from os import *
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("200x20")

def window(x, y, w, h):

    display = tk.Toplevel()
```

the line below generates the error:

```
    display.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    tk.Label(display, text="sensitive info").pack()


def main():
    path = "~/Desktop/media_argeology/Check_sensitive/"
    system("mkdir -p {0}".format(path) )    
    system("screencapture {0}temp.png".format(path) ) 
    system('sips -Z 4000 temp.png')


    image = Image.open('temp.png')
    with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
        api.SetImage(image)
        boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
        for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
            window(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])


    print "exit first function"



main()
root.mainloop()
```

i am very new to python but i do have some prior programming experience in other languages. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might have a mix of tab and spaces in your code. That's the best guess I have

Comment: ok ill give it a check

Comment: You can even see it in the source of the question. The `display = ...` line is indented with a tab, the line below with four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spaces are the preferred method for indentation**

Are you sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation white space? (That will cause that error.)

Note, it is recommended that you don't use tabs in  Python program

Check out [Tabs or spaces?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that you are mixing tabulation and four spaces indentation in your code. Check your code in editor that is able to highlight tabs and replace them to four spaces.